# How to get all URLs of images in folder from firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a storage on firestore that has a folder with images called barber. I want to list all the urls in this folder using getDownloadUrl method below. The console log return storage object not found. Can someone tell me what i do wrong,please?

```
const mypicks = getRef(storage,'barber/')

 getDownloadURL(mypicks)
  .then((url) => {
    // `url` is the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'

    // This can be downloaded directly:
    // const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    // xhr.onload = (event) => {
    //   const blob = xhr.response;
    // };
    // xhr.open('GET', url);
    // xhr.send();

    // Or inserted into an <img> element
   console.log('url',url)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle any errors
    console.log(error)
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`listAll()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files) to list all items in a directory and then get their download URLs.

```
import { ref, listAll } from "firebase/storage";

// Create a reference under which you want to list
const myPicks = ref(storage, 'barber/')

listAll(myPicks)
  .then(async (res) => {
    const { items } = res;
    const urls = await Promise.all(
      items.map((item) => getDownloadURL(item))
    );

    // Array of download URLs of all files in that folder
    console.log(urls);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  });
```

Comment: Many thanks @dharmaraj this helped em allot after 2 hours searching for an awnser!